# WPF - How to automatically update ComboBox items after Entity Framework DbContext saveChanges()?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

So right now, I have a table with columns `EmployeeID, EmployeeName`. I also have a `ComboBox` in my WPF application that displays the `EmployeeName`. I used the `Entity Framework's Code First From Database` to generate a `DbContext` called `MyDbContext` and a class called `Employee`.

Everytime I create a new `Employee`, how do I get this combobox to automatically update with the new Employee name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I were you I would use following approach:

1. Add event to `EmployeeService` called `EmployeeCreated`
2. Invoke `EmployeeCreated` event every time you successfully add new employee
3. Subscribe to `EmployeeCreated` event
4. Update combobox items when event is invoked

P.S I'm assuming you have service tier available and you are not interacting with `DbContext` directly.

Comment: I don't think I have any good resource available right out of my mind, but you could search for design patterns by martin fowler that is a good resource. Also, you can browse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/ for M$ suggested practices.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to create an ObservableCollection, perhaps can call it Employees. Bind your combobox itemsource to Employees.
Implement INotifyPropertyChange interface in your view model if you are using MVVM or simply in your DataContext class and raise the PropertyChanged event each time your collection changes.
Everytime you update your Employees, changes should reflect on the UI.